# Decrypt an RSA message from browser with window.crypto.subtle APIs

Tags: javascript, rsa, encryption-asymmetric, window.crypto

I'm trying to decode an RSA 2048 bit message encoded with a public key using the corresponding private key. The environment is google chrome and I'm using the `window.crypto.subtle` APIs.

I generated the key couple and encoded the message using `openssl` tools:

```
# generate keys and put the private one in file private_key.pem
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out private_key.pem -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048

# extract public key in file public_key.pem
openssl rsa -pubout -in private_key.pem -out public_key.pem

# encode message input.txt using the public key
openssl rsautl -encrypt -oaep -inkey public_key.pem -pubin -in input.txt -out msg_rsa.enc

# convert the encoded msg in base 64 format
base64 msg_rsa.enc > msg_rsa_64.enc
```

This is the javascript code I'm using to decode the message:

```
function str2ab(str) {
    const buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length);
    const bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
    for (let i = 0, strLen = str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
        bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return buf;
}

async function importPrivateKey(pem) {
    pem = pem.replace( /[\r\n]+/gm, "" );
    // fetch the part of the PEM string between header and footer
    const pemHeader = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----";
    const pemFooter = "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";
    const pemContents = pem.substring(pemHeader.length, pem.length - pemFooter.length);
    // base64 decode the string to get the binary data
    const binaryDerString = window.atob(pemContents);
    // convert from a binary string to an ArrayBuffer
    const binaryDer = str2ab(binaryDerString);

    return window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
      "pkcs8",
      binaryDer,
      {
        name: "RSA-OAEP",
        modulusLength: 2048,
        publicExponent: new Uint8Array([1, 0, 1]),
        hash: "SHA-256",
      },
      true,
      ["decrypt"]
    );
}

async function decryptRSA(_key, ciphertext) {
    let decrypted = await window.crypto.subtle.decrypt(
      {
        name: "RSA-OAEP"
      },
      _key,
      ciphertext
    );
    const dec = new TextDecoder();
    return dec.decode(decrypted);
}

const fromBase64 = base64String => Uint8Array.from(atob(base64String), c => c.charCodeAt(0));

window.onload = init;

async function init() {

    const privateKey = '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\
MIIEvwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKkwggSlAgEAAoIBAQC3jmTi3O1k2YXs\
AM6nNTTIzDq5YWkxYrYb6cpO9eYuzmphgRnVDR6a1YWRXMoCuCfuNXcDGywzudRn\
bBMw0FHKLUqCttVHGpZYu0+0tRR10ubxiz/xnd/aCmRYHcmUNn8Qdh3KU59A9HK5\
HhYFf1vhK8r3fkoO4CjoGo1ROzXyMybUSy+4mSNscUtt5LwrVn48vXvG5i5B4DRT\
nM4cINmutEzA2s5cDt+dzU4Py71fKBRDRIGGn0vdVSoZKbWuhm5WewyRewCk7HFc\
PALCi5/1A7VKDAHUC4FlXmuG2+wzdchEyxMj6oLR7+BkKFQaTmuMM/22cGBjVTVt\
pSr3iDovAgMBAAECggEBAIuTQW+oovNu3IDq1DkdIjgV5AmW4tBkySlMi0OjhBbP\
auEdtDDnOwBtoJU6Q3nx4psmGItKHEBw6+yAp88UeT0NV30x3delhfGO7Trx/s7h\
Qi8lvcfSTqeUA11luSR0lAZGaryw/YX820eccw5XG9yK2ll7tIC/PxvPJOpB5fF2\
XGxGrionTjHDzXJ1OWX0i0aZlNNufInJAHhlt7aT3GiQMKcQs+AUb/+bWxI3Hln8\
KcL13EUlD4pJW8vtTK3gCnQNKKMoPB5Ugqe5BrU8ElkBz+zSKDnVwt5bgjrlucYz\
rKJxWr6/qTRZkzmvkhaJeNzzepfwkFsQ/eHcxYrtuDECgYEA8OXkQ2SqYDZwizCd\
SuVkx2zHm3zXYRSlRtnXYoUdJyTyuZ4k2GvXBrlwRsOJ14emVkHKyR5enmNjwrW5\
dcD2tbBzavcqOYAMiHcKklcS/gWgPx0X5QFHU33vr8u51BQWCz75lxddWNKxVAN/\
cUTugONtS4+EP4dSZhuxHt6RscsCgYEAwxA9QmZrI54hjMkIyqwmviRmIk42S5kk\
OxbhxBbt5qVueLRB092JyGmCR2kYiqdHCYkGFDOE4kni6Bsszq5CSJvhiATFeZeX\
ldFQeZqAiRY2rAd7xD1upMug/cK3ODA8k3k/e72CtyxtBTR01q29SnPx5p/57MrI\
3ogddHlGvK0CgYEA3VqhELwjQh1D9OJK5lM683SlRd7FGdOauyvYmhKu4xU0ZBNI\
0ATnpKoo3R04P+/JjGEQMRXS4794H6ZUMDuLdxAYPiW3ivZ6jbq04BtavEf3I4dc\
OXWfULzbzbFpo9KBHvxS4974S3Hut8AvDqnEbnKML25EmwuBT4oKis8BGVkCgYEA\
nusPDZbFeNou+TUbzYrdcZHUB+TyhTq58s4clxYbMgrbaslozAQ0aavT8Pvle6j2\
zgTth+3FOFr72x+wrJ358I/W+Wrxu7NOU0eZqci/KXCIkDT0l5d5GhewDK3jeYqK\
/5cLqnNmGHfARjpLak9X5V162erBwjIf3nTEkozvnW0CgYB6L1CX3DkTFH3OBcJe\
SvV18RDUfNI8MpUKcpofmwwvgER3GrehSZHRVxVwNbnJOqbh/oiwmmNJieKrFsk9\
EzCRBVWdZByHHYW2js+gCrAp+ghnl1QEAeCU7YTxCJ2fZIAmfB9X4u/7ARtVxnZY\
mOWlm65KUYr5lf2Ws5plL4pCRA==\
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----';

    const ciphertext = 'F6/NwENdUZSl+vrgpWVkyWPQuYaTGDNZPIvj4KmIRHVx4qybxN24LPIgk0Rl84KHcLFadZWCjNpM\
vg3l826OaKZAtwvIp9IxVrMbvtNOymY6A1koKvC9ema92SR4DC9hmTtMxhUB6r3XgACtRLFqMfg+\
zYSHfFqQEGJg3yZ43hfzIq/gCfHPk5sZXASq5WY5b9yd4gRonn5D4OCD6xna/r5ovHfrpO/Fwe8N\
eeY2gqTAdtzvtmOw/HLQhGANejpJYr1IriQbepM7jLjBkJX+uCn38O1MxpQb7s5RXTvGvoEoofWV\
Cq8gNFhgnVFuurdZUiY0bn58UwaVFdwzEfDSUQ==';

    try {
        const key = await importPrivateKey(privateKey);
        const decoded = await decryptRSA(key, fromBase64(ciphertext));
        console.log(decoded);
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Running the code, I got an exception in `window.crypto.subtle.decrypt` with the rather useless message "DOMException".

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: The documentation from w3c is written to be as nearly unreadable as possible. My guess is that you're suppose to base64-decode the private key yourself and pass the result into `importKey`. So throw away the 'BEGIN...' and 'END...' line, base64 decode the thing in the middle and pass that to importKey. If that doesn't work then I don't have any other ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's only one flaw: The posted code currently uses OAEP with *SHA256*. The ciphertext can be decrypted with the posted key if OAEP with *SHA1* is applied as padding.

In addition, the function `fromBase64` can be used to Base64 decode the key into a `TypedArray`, so the function `str2ab` is actually not needed (but of course this is not an error, just redundant).

```js
const fromBase64 = base64String => Uint8Array.from(atob(base64String), c => c.charCodeAt(0));
const getPkcs8Der = pkcs8Pem => {
    pkcs8Pem = pkcs8Pem.replace( /[\r\n]+/gm, "" );
    const pkcs8PemHeader = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----";
    const pkcs8PemFooter = "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";
    pkcs8Pem = pkcs8Pem.substring(pkcs8PemHeader.length, pkcs8Pem.length - pkcs8PemFooter.length);
    return fromBase64(pkcs8Pem); 
}  
  
async function importPrivateKey(pkcs8Pem) {  
    return await window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
        "pkcs8",
        getPkcs8Der(pkcs8Pem),
        {
            name: "RSA-OAEP",
            hash: "SHA-1",          // Replace SHA-256 with SHA-1
        },
        true,
        ["decrypt"]
    );
}

async function decryptRSA(key, ciphertext) {
    let decrypted = await window.crypto.subtle.decrypt(
        {
            name: "RSA-OAEP"
        },
        key,
        ciphertext
    );
    const dec = new TextDecoder();
    return dec.decode(decrypted);
}

window.onload = init;

async function init() {

    const privateKey = 
        '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\
        MIIEvwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKkwggSlAgEAAoIBAQC3jmTi3O1k2YXs\
        AM6nNTTIzDq5YWkxYrYb6cpO9eYuzmphgRnVDR6a1YWRXMoCuCfuNXcDGywzudRn\
        bBMw0FHKLUqCttVHGpZYu0+0tRR10ubxiz/xnd/aCmRYHcmUNn8Qdh3KU59A9HK5\
        HhYFf1vhK8r3fkoO4CjoGo1ROzXyMybUSy+4mSNscUtt5LwrVn48vXvG5i5B4DRT\
        nM4cINmutEzA2s5cDt+dzU4Py71fKBRDRIGGn0vdVSoZKbWuhm5WewyRewCk7HFc\
        PALCi5/1A7VKDAHUC4FlXmuG2+wzdchEyxMj6oLR7+BkKFQaTmuMM/22cGBjVTVt\
        pSr3iDovAgMBAAECggEBAIuTQW+oovNu3IDq1DkdIjgV5AmW4tBkySlMi0OjhBbP\
        auEdtDDnOwBtoJU6Q3nx4psmGItKHEBw6+yAp88UeT0NV30x3delhfGO7Trx/s7h\
        Qi8lvcfSTqeUA11luSR0lAZGaryw/YX820eccw5XG9yK2ll7tIC/PxvPJOpB5fF2\
        XGxGrionTjHDzXJ1OWX0i0aZlNNufInJAHhlt7aT3GiQMKcQs+AUb/+bWxI3Hln8\
        KcL13EUlD4pJW8vtTK3gCnQNKKMoPB5Ugqe5BrU8ElkBz+zSKDnVwt5bgjrlucYz\
        rKJxWr6/qTRZkzmvkhaJeNzzepfwkFsQ/eHcxYrtuDECgYEA8OXkQ2SqYDZwizCd\
        SuVkx2zHm3zXYRSlRtnXYoUdJyTyuZ4k2GvXBrlwRsOJ14emVkHKyR5enmNjwrW5\
        dcD2tbBzavcqOYAMiHcKklcS/gWgPx0X5QFHU33vr8u51BQWCz75lxddWNKxVAN/\
        cUTugONtS4+EP4dSZhuxHt6RscsCgYEAwxA9QmZrI54hjMkIyqwmviRmIk42S5kk\
        OxbhxBbt5qVueLRB092JyGmCR2kYiqdHCYkGFDOE4kni6Bsszq5CSJvhiATFeZeX\
        ldFQeZqAiRY2rAd7xD1upMug/cK3ODA8k3k/e72CtyxtBTR01q29SnPx5p/57MrI\
        3ogddHlGvK0CgYEA3VqhELwjQh1D9OJK5lM683SlRd7FGdOauyvYmhKu4xU0ZBNI\
        0ATnpKoo3R04P+/JjGEQMRXS4794H6ZUMDuLdxAYPiW3ivZ6jbq04BtavEf3I4dc\
        OXWfULzbzbFpo9KBHvxS4974S3Hut8AvDqnEbnKML25EmwuBT4oKis8BGVkCgYEA\
        nusPDZbFeNou+TUbzYrdcZHUB+TyhTq58s4clxYbMgrbaslozAQ0aavT8Pvle6j2\
        zgTth+3FOFr72x+wrJ358I/W+Wrxu7NOU0eZqci/KXCIkDT0l5d5GhewDK3jeYqK\
        /5cLqnNmGHfARjpLak9X5V162erBwjIf3nTEkozvnW0CgYB6L1CX3DkTFH3OBcJe\
        SvV18RDUfNI8MpUKcpofmwwvgER3GrehSZHRVxVwNbnJOqbh/oiwmmNJieKrFsk9\
        EzCRBVWdZByHHYW2js+gCrAp+ghnl1QEAeCU7YTxCJ2fZIAmfB9X4u/7ARtVxnZY\
        mOWlm65KUYr5lf2Ws5plL4pCRA==\
        -----END PRIVATE KEY-----';

    const ciphertext =
        'F6/NwENdUZSl+vrgpWVkyWPQuYaTGDNZPIvj4KmIRHVx4qybxN24LPIgk0Rl84KHcLFadZWCjNpM\
        vg3l826OaKZAtwvIp9IxVrMbvtNOymY6A1koKvC9ema92SR4DC9hmTtMxhUB6r3XgACtRLFqMfg+\
        zYSHfFqQEGJg3yZ43hfzIq/gCfHPk5sZXASq5WY5b9yd4gRonn5D4OCD6xna/r5ovHfrpO/Fwe8N\
        eeY2gqTAdtzvtmOw/HLQhGANejpJYr1IriQbepM7jLjBkJX+uCn38O1MxpQb7s5RXTvGvoEoofWV\
        Cq8gNFhgnVFuurdZUiY0bn58UwaVFdwzEfDSUQ==';

    try {
        const key = await importPrivateKey(privateKey);
        const decrypted = await decryptRSA(key, fromBase64(ciphertext));
        console.log(decrypted);
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Topaco. You saved my day! Just a couple of questions: the SHA-1 is related to the couple of RSA keys or to the encryption algorithm? Do you know how to force openssl to adopt SHA-256 when generating keys / encoding instead of the default SHA-1? Thanks again!

Comment: The digest plays a role for the OAEP padding chosen in the example. OAEP pads the message to the key size and ensures that even with the same key and the same plaintext, different ciphertexts result for security reasons. In this respect, the digest is neither a property of the key nor of the encryption algorithm itself, which could perhaps be deduced from `window.crypto.subtle.importKey`, but this is not true. OAEP padding is described in detail in [RFC 8017, Section 7.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8017#section-7.1).

Comment: `openssl rsautl` applies SHA1 for OAEP, this is fix and can't be changed [here](https://superuser.com/a/1016697). But it's possible to use `openssl -pkeyutl`, which allows OAEP with SHA256 [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/pkeyutl.html), e.g. for encryption: `openssl pkeyutl -in plaintext.txt -out ciphertext.txt -encrypt -pubin -inkey publicX509.pem -pkeyopt rsa_padding_mode:oaep -pkeyopt rsa_mgf1_md:sha256`.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Just for sake of correctness: the option for OAEP mode is rsa_oaep_md:sha256 and not rsa_mgf1_md:sha256

Comment: OAEP uses digests in two places, (1) as a basis for the mask generation function MGF1 and (2) for the hashing of the OAEP label (RFC 8017)(https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8017). `rsa_oaep_md` sets _both_ digests, whereas `rsa_mgf1_md` sets _only_ the MGF1-digest. The default of both digests is SHA1. I.e. the option `rsa_oaep_md:sha256` _alone_ sets both digests to SHA256, whereas the option `rsa_mgf1_md:sha256` _alone_ sets only the MGF1-digest to SHA256 (i.e. the label-digest is still SHA1). Only [`rsa_mgf1_md`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/pkeyutl.html) is documented.